# Swift. How to get the previous character?

Tags: swift, character

For example: I have character "b" and I what to get "a", so "a" is the previous character.

```
let b: Character = "b"
let a: Character = b - 1 // Compilation error
```

Comment: You can create an array with the alphabet and simply call the letters by index

Comment: If we are talking simple ASCII characters you could do something like `if let ascii = b.asciiValue { a = Character(UnicodeScalar(ascii - 1)) }` but maybe with a bit more advanced error handling depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty complicated to get the previous character from Swift's `Character` type because `Character` is actually comprised of one or more `Unicode.Scalar` values. Depending on your needs you could restrict your efforts to just the ASCII characters. Or you could support all characters comprised of a single Unicode scalar. Once you get into characters comprised of multiple Unicode scalars (such as the flag Emojis or various skin toned Emojis) then I'm not even sure what the "previous character" means.

Here is a pair of methods added to a `Character` extension that can handle ASCII and single-Unicode scalar characters.

```
extension Character {
    var previousASCII: Character? {
        if let ascii = asciiValue, ascii > 0 {
            return Character(Unicode.Scalar(ascii - 1))
        }

        return nil
    }

    var previousScalar: Character? {
        if unicodeScalars.count == 1 {
            if let scalar = unicodeScalars.first, scalar.value > 0 {
                if let prev = Unicode.Scalar(scalar.value - 1) {
                    return Character(prev)
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let b: Character = "b"
let a = b.previousASCII // Gives Optional("a")
```

```
let emoji: Character = ""
let previous = emoji.previousScalar // Gives Optional("")
```